# How and when did the plasma get replaced with water? And who?

Tags: plot-explanation, family-business

In the 1989 movie, *Family Business*, Jessie McMullen, his son Vito, and Vito's son Adam plan a heist from a lab. They go inside, retrieve plasma (it has color) and place them in a hard case and go out.

The youngest realizes they didn't retrieve the book that is essential for their 1 million dollars trophy. So he comes back to the building and retrieves the book. But because of his inexperience he suddenly set the alarm before leaving.

He hands the book to the other two before police arrives and arrest him. The two leave with plasma and the book with their car prior to the detention.

The two meet a corrupted lawyer who tells them if you want me to help you about Adam you should give some of the plasma to me which they agree.

Jessie hides the plasma in his house. Vito goes to his house to retrieve the plasma and send it to the lawyer. Jessie is not in the house. But his lover hands the case with plasma inside to Vito. Vito send them to the lawyer without opening the case.

A few hours later the lawyer calls Vito and tells him you just sent me 8 tubes of water.

How and when did the plasma get replaced with water?  Who replaced it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [source novel](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/2034316) the implication is that Jessie took the plasma out of the vials and put it into different containers, then *filled the vials with tapwater and hid them in his house*, knowing (or at least suspecting) that he might get double-crossed.

> His [Vito's] first thought was that **Jessie had screwed him beautifully. The
> real stuff was safely hidden away and Jessie had bought himself the
> time he needed.** Margie might well have been in on the swindle,
> although he doubted it. He couldn't imagine her being that good an
> actress nor could he imagine Jessie trusting a woman.

The 'plasmids' turn up later, safely in Jessie's possession.

> Elaine and Vito had checked into a nearby motel, still not knowing
> whether the New York police had found Jessie. Dempsey had called their
> room later that night; **Jessie had been arrested and the plasmids found
> in his refrigerator.** He had already told the New York DA that he had
> no intention of "rolling over and playing dead," and would not waive
> extradition. Finding the plasmids had made all the difference in the
> deal that Dempsey cut with the DA.

Comment: So the plasmids have not been sold at all. But Jessie took money from Adam's ex-teacher.